# Ubuntu 22.04 Mediatek mt7921e forever wifi connecting (configuring)

Tags: networking, wireless, mediatek

Previously the wireless connection work normally, but now it always shows Wi-Fi Connecting. Last day I installed nvidia driver and cudnn stuff for tensorflow (with errors, but fortunately fixed). I also encountered a reboot issue mentioning `failed unmounting kvm exiting virtualization` yesterday (but, now the error is gone). Are those problems related? How to fix this?

The problem look like this.

[image]

This is how `nmcli d` output

[image]

Note that currently I connected to the internet using usb tethering.

What i have done:

1. Reloading mt7921e module with `modprobe`
2. Reinstall `linux-firmware` using `apt`