# Mediatek MT7921 WLAN stuck on connecting, or no/intermittent pages display

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, mediatek

MEDIATEK MT7921 WLAN will not connect, or connects but no pages display, or they display after several minutes.

I have not encountered an issue using this at home or anywhere when tethered to my Pixel 5A WLAN hotspot, but here at a large campus library, where I can see a white Cisco access point, a few metres away, the connection is almost always failing to connect with the icon circling, or intermittent, or showing as connected but no pages display, or they take up to a minute to come through. Ping replies from the default gateway also come and go when marked connected. The local WLAN itself seems to be fine, my tablet and phone connect without issue and do not experience slow speeds and there are hundreds of people on this floor using it.

I am running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS with kernel 6.2.0-33-generic on my Asus Zenbook UX325UAZ. If relevant I experience a similar issue with Bluetooh on the same device, where my mouse with randomly stop working and Bluetooth cannot be enabled, though this happens much less frequently than the WLAN NIC issue. Of the similarly reported issues most mention kernel 5.21 included a patch for this card.

When attempting to use a Asus USB-N10 it did appear in my panel menu but the on board scanning at the same time seemed to interfere and I have not yet been able to properly disable that so I could just try using the USB.

I did read something about powering off completely rather than rebooting when the issue occurs, and that along with making sure the power cable was connected when I booted after the shutdown has allowed my laptop to connect temporarily but now the WLAN icon in my top panel shows connected but no pages display, and then the pages do display or are slow to load.

Below some logs and things I have tried when failing to connect, icon spinning repeatedly. Pinging the default gateway results in destination unreachable, every 20 or so replies no route to host. I am not dual booting and never have on this laptop.

The issue is ongoing. I read somewhere it would be worth checking secure boot, and/or possibly fast boot or something else in the BIOS? Is there anything obvious from the info below or is there anything else  I can try please?

`sudo lshw -class network`

```
*-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: MT7921 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlp1s0
       version: 00
       serial: 90:e8:68:43:fb:b3
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=mt7921e driverversion=6.2.0-33-generic firmware=____010000-20220209150915 ip=137.43.30.114 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:87 memory:e0300000-e03fffff memory:e0400000-e0403fff memory:e0404000-e0404fff
```

`lspci -nnk`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne Root Complex [1022:1630]
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne Root Complex [1022:1630]
00:00.2 IOMMU [0806]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne IOMMU [1022:1631]
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne IOMMU [1022:1631]
00:01.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1632]
00:01.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge [1022:1634]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:01.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge [1022:1634]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:02.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1632]
00:02.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge [1022:1634]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:08.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1632]
00:08.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus [1022:1635]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:14.0 SMBus [0c05]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller [1022:790b] (rev 51)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. FCH SMBus Controller [1043:1c02]
    Kernel driver in use: piix4_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_piix4, sp5100_tco
00:14.3 ISA bridge [0601]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge [1022:790e] (rev 51)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. FCH LPC Bridge [1043:1c02]
00:18.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 0 [1022:1448]
00:18.1 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 1 [1022:1449]
00:18.2 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 2 [1022:144a]
00:18.3 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 3 [1022:144b]
    Kernel driver in use: k10temp
    Kernel modules: k10temp
00:18.4 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 4 [1022:144c]
00:18.5 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 5 [1022:144d]
00:18.6 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 6 [1022:144e]
00:18.7 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 7 [1022:144f]
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7921 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter [14c3:7961]
    Subsystem: AzureWave Device [1a3b:4680]
    Kernel driver in use: mt7921e
    Kernel modules: mt7921e
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:522a] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader [1043:202f]
    Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
    Kernel modules: rtsx_pci
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: SK hynix Gold P31 SSD [1c5c:174a]
    Subsystem: SK hynix Gold P31 SSD [1c5c:174a]
    Kernel driver in use: nvme
    Kernel modules: nvme
04:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Lucienne [1002:164c] (rev c2)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Lucienne [1043:1c02]
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
04:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio Controller [1002:1637]
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio Controller [1043:1c02]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
04:00.2 Encryption controller [1080]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor [1022:15df]
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor [1022:15df]
    Kernel driver in use: ccp
    Kernel modules: ccp
04:00.3 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1 [1022:1639]
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1 [1043:1c02]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci
04:00.4 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1 [1022:1639]
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1 [1043:1c02]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci
04:00.5 Multimedia controller [0480]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor [1022:15e2] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor [1043:1c02]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_rn_pci_acp3x
    Kernel modules: snd_pci_acp3x, snd_rn_pci_acp3x, snd_pci_acp5x, snd_pci_acp6x, snd_acp_pci, snd_rpl_pci_acp6x, snd_pci_ps, snd_sof_amd_renoir, snd_sof_amd_rembrandt
04:00.6 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller [1022:15e3]
    DeviceName: HD Audio Controller
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller [1043:1c02]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

`lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network`

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7921 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter [14c3:7961]
    Subsystem: AzureWave Device [1a3b:4680]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 87
    IOMMU group: 8
    Region 0: Memory at e0300000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Region 2: Memory at e0400000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Region 4: Memory at e0404000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
```

`rfkill list`

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

`apt info linux-firmware -a | grep Version`

```
Version: 20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.18
Version: 20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.14
Version: 20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu1
```

`modinfo mt7921e | grep alias`

```
alias:          pci:v000014C3d00000616sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014C3d00000608sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014C3d00007922sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014C3d00007961sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
```

`lsmod | grep mt7921`

```
mt7921e                28672  0
mt7921_common         114688  1 mt7921e
mt76_connac_lib        90112  2 mt7921e,mt7921_common
mt76                  122880  3 mt7921e,mt7921_common,mt76_connac_lib
mac80211             1617920  3 mt76,mt7921_common,mt76_connac_lib
cfg80211             1241088  4 mt76,mac80211,mt7921_common,mt76_connac_lib
```

```
modinfo mt7921e | grep -i version
srcversion:     E328FAB2A274BDA6C4B7CAB
vermagic:       6.2.0-33-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions
```

No output for `dkms status`.

`dmesg -w | grep wlan`

```
[   16.031268] mt7921e 0000:01:00.0 wlp1s0: renamed from wlan0
```

`sudo journalctl -fu NetworkManager`

```
Sep 20 18:34:55 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695231295.8722] device (wlp1s0): disconnecting for new activation request.
Sep 20 18:34:55 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695231295.8723] device (wlp1s0): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'new-activation', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 20 18:34:55 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695231295.8740] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Sep 20 18:34:55 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695231295.8744] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="c169499c-3671-442a-9c68-abc394f0f4f3" name="Campus Wireless" pid=2896 uid=1000 result="success"
Sep 20 18:34:56 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695231296.2603] device (wlp1s0): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'new-activation', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 20 18:34:56 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695231296.2913] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Sep 20 18:34:56 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695231296.2913] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Sep 20 18:34:56 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695231296.2913] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): state changed no lease
Sep 20 18:34:56 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695231296.3322] device (wlp1s0): Activation: starting connection 'Campus Wireless' (c169499c-3671-442a-9c68-abc394f0f4f3)
Sep 20 18:34:56 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695231296.3325] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Sep 20 18:34:56 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695231296.3333] device (wlp1s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 20 18:34:56 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695231296.3336] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Sep 20 18:34:56 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695231296.3341] device (wlp1s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 20 18:34:56 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695231296.3344] device (wlp1s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'Campus Wireless' requires no security.  No secrets needed.
Sep 20 18:34:56 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695231296.3345] Config: added 'ssid' value 'Campus Wireless'
Sep 20 18:34:56 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695231296.3345] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Sep 20 18:34:56 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695231296.3345] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
Sep 20 18:34:56 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695231296.3345] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'NONE'
Sep 20 18:34:56 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695231296.3900] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
Sep 20 18:34:56 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695231296.3952] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Sep 20 18:34:56 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695231296.6165] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> completed
Sep 20 18:34:56 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695231296.6166] device (wlp1s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "Campus Wireless"
Sep 20 18:34:56 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695231296.6168] device (wlp1s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 20 18:34:56 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695231296.6174] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Sep 20 18:35:05 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695231305.9680] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): state changed new lease, address=137.43.30.114
Sep 20 18:35:05 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695231305.9748] device (wlp1s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 20 18:35:05 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695231305.9769] device (wlp1s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 20 18:35:05 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695231305.9770] device (wlp1s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 20 18:35:05 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695231305.9773] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Sep 20 18:35:05 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695231305.9777] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Sep 20 18:35:05 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695231305.9778] policy: set 'Campus Wireless' (wlp1s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Sep 20 18:35:05 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695231305.9783] device (wlp1s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Sep 20 18:35:05 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695231305.9786] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL         --
```

`sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager`

Again `sudo journalctl -fu NetworkManager`

```
Sep 20 18:51:05 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695232265.1441] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> authenticating
Sep 20 18:51:05 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695232265.1442] device (wlp1s0): ip:dhcp4: restarting
Sep 20 18:51:05 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695232265.1442] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Sep 20 18:51:05 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695232265.1442] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Sep 20 18:51:05 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695232265.1542] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Sep 20 18:51:05 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695232265.3874] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> completed
Sep 20 18:51:43 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695232303.7352] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> authenticating
Sep 20 18:51:43 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695232303.7353] device (wlp1s0): ip:dhcp4: restarting
Sep 20 18:51:43 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695232303.7355] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Sep 20 18:51:43 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695232303.7357] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Sep 20 18:51:43 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695232303.7412] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Sep 20 18:51:43 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695232303.8399] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> completed
Sep 20 18:52:29 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695232349.0491] device (wlp1s0): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 20 18:52:29 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695232349.0495] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Sep 20 18:52:29 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <warn>  [1695232349.0500] device (wlp1s0): Activation: failed for connection 'Campus Wireless'
Sep 20 18:52:29 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695232349.0503] device (wlp1s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 20 18:52:29 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695232349.0519] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Sep 20 18:52:29 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695232349.2106] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Sep 20 18:52:29 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695232349.5627] policy: auto-activating connection 'Campus Wireless' (c169499c-3671-442a-9c68-abc394f0f4f3)
Sep 20 18:52:29 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695232349.5634] device (wlp1s0): Activation: starting connection 'Campus Wireless' (c169499c-3671-442a-9c68-abc394f0f4f3)
Sep 20 18:52:29 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695232349.5636] device (wlp1s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 20 18:52:29 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695232349.5642] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Sep 20 18:52:29 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695232349.5647] device (wlp1s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 20 18:52:29 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695232349.5651] device (wlp1s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'Campus Wireless' requires no security.  No secrets needed.
Sep 20 18:52:29 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695232349.5652] Config: added 'ssid' value 'Campus Wireless'
Sep 20 18:52:29 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695232349.5652] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Sep 20 18:52:29 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695232349.5652] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
Sep 20 18:52:29 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695232349.5652] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'NONE'
Sep 20 18:52:33 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695232353.5974] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Sep 20 18:52:37 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695232357.3487] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Sep 20 18:52:37 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695232357.3617] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Sep 20 18:52:37 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695232357.5640] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> completed
Sep 20 18:52:37 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695232357.5641] device (wlp1s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "Campus Wireless"
Sep 20 18:52:37 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695232357.5644] device (wlp1s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 20 18:52:37 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695232357.5650] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Sep 20 18:53:16 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695232396.0168] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> authenticating
Sep 20 18:53:16 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695232396.0168] device (wlp1s0): ip:dhcp4: restarting
Sep 20 18:53:16 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695232396.0169] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Sep 20 18:53:16 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695232396.0170] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Sep 20 18:53:16 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695232396.0268] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Sep 20 18:53:16 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695232396.1233] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> completed
Sep 20 18:53:54 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695232434.4677] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> authenticating
Sep 20 18:53:54 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695232434.4678] device (wlp1s0): ip:dhcp4: restarting
Sep 20 18:53:54 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695232434.5075] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Sep 20 18:53:54 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695232434.5076] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Sep 20 18:53:54 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695232434.5094] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Sep 20 18:53:54 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695232434.5585] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> completed
Sep 20 18:54:40 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695232480.0521] device (wlp1s0): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 20 18:54:40 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695232480.0526] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Sep 20 18:54:40 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <warn>  [1695232480.0529] device (wlp1s0): Activation: failed for connection 'Campus Wireless'
Sep 20 18:54:40 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695232480.0533] device (wlp1s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 20 18:54:40 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695232480.0952] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Sep 20 18:54:40 mechanism NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1695232480.2460] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
```

`mcli general logging level TRACE domains ALL`

```
Sep 20 19:03:00 mechanism NetworkManager[9547]: <trace> [1695232980.9937] auth: call[116]: CheckAuthorization(org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.scan), subject=unix-process[pid=2896, uid=1000, start=6234]
Sep 20 19:03:00 mechanism NetworkManager[9547]: <trace> [1695232980.9977] auth: call[116]: completed: authorized=1, challenge=0
Sep 20 19:03:00 mechanism NetworkManager[9547]: <debug> [1695232980.9978] device[e65947e8dd6924f9] (wlp1s0): wifi-scan: start explicit scan (0 SSIDs to probe scan)
Sep 20 19:03:00 mechanism NetworkManager[9547]: <trace> [1695232980.9978] device[e65947e8dd6924f9] (wlp1s0): wifi-scan: kickoff: explicit scan starting
Sep 20 19:03:00 mechanism NetworkManager[9547]: <trace> [1695232980.9979] sup-iface[c0ee356e21f5cf39,2,wlp1s0]: request-scan: request scanning (0 ssids)...
Sep 20 19:03:00 mechanism NetworkManager[9547]: <debug> [1695232980.9980] device[e65947e8dd6924f9] (wlp1s0): wifi-scan: scanning-state: scanning
Sep 20 19:03:00 mechanism NetworkManager[9547]: <trace> [1695232980.9980] device[e65947e8dd6924f9] (wlp1s0): wifi-scan: kickoff: don't scan (has scan_request_cancellable)
Sep 20 19:03:00 mechanism NetworkManager[9547]: <trace> [1695232980.9988] sup-iface[c0ee356e21f5cf39,2,wlp1s0]: request-scan: request scanning success
Sep 20 19:03:00 mechanism NetworkManager[9547]: <trace> [1695232980.9988] device[e65947e8dd6924f9] (wlp1s0): wifi-scan: scan request completed (D-Bus request)
Sep 20 19:03:01 mechanism NetworkManager[9547]: <trace> [1695232981.0227] sup-iface[c0ee356e21f5cf39,2,wlp1s0]: scanning: yes (plain property)
Sep 20 19:03:01 mechanism NetworkManager[9547]: <trace> [1695232981.0228] sup-iface[c0ee356e21f5cf39,2,wlp1s0]: scanning: yes
Sep 20 19:03:01 mechanism NetworkManager[9547]: <trace> [1695232981.2353] ndisc[0x560700838570,"wlp1s0"]: solicit: router solicitation sent
Sep 20 19:03:01 mechanism NetworkManager[9547]: <debug> [1695232981.2353] ndisc[0x560700838570,"wlp1s0"]: solicit: schedule sending next solicitation in 29.471 seconds
Sep 20 19:03:01 mechanism NetworkManager[9547]: <trace> [1695232981.4998] device[e65947e8dd6924f9] (wlp1s0): wifi-scan: scan request completed (after extra delay)
Sep 20 19:03:05 mechanism NetworkManager[9547]: <debug> [1695232985.2632] device[e65947e8dd6924f9] (wlp1s0): ip:ac6: timeout for autoconf (IPv6 router advertisement) reached
Sep 20 19:03:05 mechanism NetworkManager[9547]: <debug> [1695232985.2633] device[e65947e8dd6924f9] (wlp1s0): ip:ac6: set state: fail (was pending)
Sep 20 19:03:05 mechanism NetworkManager[9547]: <trace> [1695232985.2633] device[e65947e8dd6924f9] (wlp1s0): ip6: check-state: state pending => fail, is_failed=1, is_pending=0, is_started=1 temp_na=0, may-fail-4=1, may-fail-6=1;; manualip4=done dhcp4=done; manualip6=done ll6=done ac6=fail
Sep 20 19:03:05 mechanism NetworkManager[9547]: <debug> [1695232985.2633] device[e65947e8dd6924f9] (wlp1s0): ip6: set state fail (was pending, reason: check-ip-state)
Sep 20 19:03:05 mechanism NetworkManager[9547]: <trace> [1695232985.2634] device[e65947e8dd6924f9] (wlp1s0): ip: check-state: (combined) state done => done
Sep 20 19:03:07 mechanism NetworkManager[9547]: <trace> [1695232987.0493] settings-connection[88e074969b3dbd31,7b4e26d6-23fc-4361-9c70-b7b8f3d57c46]: timestamp: set timestamp 1695232987
Sep 20 19:03:07 mechanism NetworkManager[9547]: <trace> [1695232987.0494] settings: [timestamps-keyfile]: updated entry for timestamps.7b4e26d6-23fc-4361-9c70-b7b8f3d57c46
Sep 20 19:03:07 mechanism NetworkManager[9547]: <trace> [1695232987.0494] settings: [timestamps-keyfile]: schedule flushing changes to disk
Sep 20 19:03:07 mechanism NetworkManager[9547]: <trace> [1695232987.0494] settings-connection[0e2087238bafb010,941b8d85-55e3-4cfa-a212-d1a9cf290bc3]: timestamp: set timestamp 1695232987
Sep 20 19:03:07 mechanism NetworkManager[9547]: <trace> [1695232987.0494] settings-connection[a8a44ac0d5147b05,014dadad-ca3a-4f47-a5ff-df3f916c6c48]: timestamp: set timestamp 1695232987
```

After editing `cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
match-device=interface-name:wlp1s0
dhcp=dhclient
```

`sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager`

Reinstalled network-manager and rebooted.

[How to install Realtek WLAN driver mt7921 in Ubuntu 22.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1464480/how-to-install-realtek-wlan-driver-mt7921-in-ubuntu-22-04)

https://devicetests.com/install-mediatek-mt7921-driver-wifi-bluetooth-ubuntu

[Ubuntu 22.04 Mediatek mt7921e forever wifi connecting (configuring)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1442432/ubuntu-22-04-mediatek-mt7921e-forever-wifi-connecting-configuring)

[Wifi not working (unavailable) 22.10 Mediatek MT7921](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1444909/wifi-not-working-unavailable-22-10-mediatek-mt7921)

[Wireless adapter (MediaTek MT7921) is not working after a reboot in Ubuntu 21.10 (probe failed with error -110)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1382918/wireless-adapter-mediatek-mt7921-is-not-working-after-a-reboot-in-ubuntu-21-10)

https://ubuntu.com/certified/component/920

Comment: Please see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/167115), run the wireless info script, and then provide a link to the output posted to pastebin. This will give all information that may be needed about your device and also some info about the local network you're trying to connect to.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that but I will not be at that location again until next week. Should I just save a copy of my post, delete it, and repost it then?

Comment: Find a different wifi card, those don't work well even in Windows

Comment: @saltyeggs It's normal to just edit your current question and add the additional information. Also after you edit, the question gets bumped up again on the main feed. I would suggest adding a comment before the link like "here's the result of the wireless info script as requested" or something along those lines and maybe even put the edit at the beginning of the question instead of at the end so it's the first thing people read.

Comment: Also, it should be noted that sometimes being too close to the AP results in a bad connection because of too much noise. Also, it might help to increase your retry count from 7 to something like 12. So: `sudo iwconfig wlp1s0 recount 12` and then verify it with `iwconfig` and it should show a recount value of 12. Of course, this will increase the number of allowed failed attempts when it sends a signal to the AP and sometimes helps with a poor signal or crowded connection.

Comment: @Jeremy31 Same, or at least similar issue with an Asus USB-BT500 Nano.

Comment: @mchid sorry for late reply, I only returned to campus recently. Please note this was resolved by upgrading as per the accepted answer. I wanted to post the wireless info output from before the upgrade in case useful to someone else: https://pastebin.com/wKRRCQuU - Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with MEDIATEK MT7921 on a freshly installed Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, as well as previous versions. It would rarely connect to the large networks of my university, both public and Eduroam. It worked fine on Windows running on the same hardware.

Today, an upgrade to Ubuntu 23.10 seems to have solved the issue.

You might have to activate non-LTS upgrades either via Software & Updates ("Updates" / "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version: For any new version") or by changing the corresponding line in `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` from `Prompt=lts` to `Prompt=normal`.

You can then upgrade using the Software Updater  or `sudo do-release-upgrade`.

Note, however, that

> It is recommended that users run an LTS release as it provides 5 years of standard support and security updates.
> – https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/upgrade-introduction

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I only returned to campus in recent weeks and I wanted to test it for awhile before posting. You fixed the issue, thank you.

Separate but possibly related issue: initially after the upgrade to 23.10 my Logitech MX Vertical mouse continued to stop working after using for a few minutes, only working again on laptop reboot. I may have caused this by one of my attempts to fix the card (which I understand is responsible for both WLAN and BT) before my OP. If the issue returns I can open a new thread, just posting in case it was something you also encountered.